# Allauth Django Login URL

Tags: django, url, authentication

allauth django

I would like to redirect a user to a "dynamic" login page.
I am currently being redirected to accounts/login

but I would like it to be

```
accounts/login/?name=Bob    for user Bob
accounts/login/?name=Carl   for user Carl
accounts/login/?name=Alice  for user Alice
```

etc ...

Note that I could change the LOGIN_URL in settings.py to be e.g. accounts/login/?name=Bob  but that would remain fixed and I would not get accounts/login/?name=Carl or accounts/login/?name=Alice.

Once the user has successfully login, I would need to retrieve the name from the request e.g. If user Bob has successfully login, get the name=Bob, etc.

Usually, I would do `request.GET.get('name','')`

but I would need to change allauth views

Is there a way to achieve the above without changing the source code of allauth.

Comment: The username shouldn't be passed in the url. The usename can easily be retrieved from request.user

Comment: actually Bob,CArl,Alice are not usernames. I could be passing anything e.g. time, prodcucts, etc. In django-allauth, is it possible to retrieve these without changing the views in the allauth source code?